# Access to label in a stack view

Tags: swift, uistackview

[image]

How can I change the textColor of the Labels in the stack view during running time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an IBOutlet property for each label in your viewController.  Connect each label to its respective property in your Xib or Storyboard by (in Xib or Storyboard) right-clicking each label and hooking up its reference outlet (By control-dragging from the reference outlet to the scene (or to your viewController in the left-side list.)

Then in your viewController, set each label's textColor at the time(s) of your choosing, such as in viewDidLoad().

There is nothing special about how to access these labels when in a stack view.  You just set up your IBOutlets as normal.

Comment: What if I have many views? Is there a way to do something like "subview.label"?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many views you have, such as how nested your stacking is.  You're accessing your labels directly.  Now if instead you mean you have many labels in a stack, you could switch to using a reference outlet collection so that you don't need a property for each label.

Answer (score 1):

Found a much easier way. Taken "weekdayLabels" is the outlet for the Outlet for the Weekdays Stack View. You can just iterate through all the contained views inside the stack view and change for example background and text colors.

```
for view in weekdayLabels.arrangedSubviews {
  view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
  (view as! UILabel).textColor = UIColor.black
}
```